# How to prevent inventory decrement on place of order

Tags: orders, event-observer, inventory

My requirement is on a specific order that inventory should not decrease from Default Stock or Quantity after placing the order. How can I Achieve it? Is it possible?

Can I get some help.? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think products have quantity setting where it does not decrease stock - its always in stock. You need to turn off MANAGE STOCK in ADVANCED INVENTORY for the product. Here is a guide: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/inventory-product-stock-options.html You should be able to do it on a global scale too within configuration. I dont remember off-top of my head.

Comment: Here is more: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/inventory.html

Comment: you need to first Manage stock `yes` in the product and then once your order status is pending or processing to shipment then it's effect to stock

Comment: thank you @viru for response, its already `Yes`

Answer (score 0):

Turn off MANAGE STOCK in ADVANCED INVENTORY of a product.

[image]

Here are some guides:

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/inventory-product-stock-options.html

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/inventory.html

Comment: Thank you for response, My requirement is I need to prevent inventory decrement for a specific `Back order` conditions , So I need to handle it programmatically, it should not affect the normal orders.